# PHP echo Username in Value field

Tags: php, sql, database

Im currently very busy with developing a website for my final-project for school. I am wondering if I can echo the username as a Value in the input.

This is what I have right now, but it won't work:

```
<input class="field" id="userNaam" placeholder="Voornaam" type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php $_SESSION['userNaam'] = $userNaam = $userSession;?>" maxlength="20" minlength="1" size="17">
</label>
```

If you know the answer, please help me out!

Thanks :) <3

Comment: yes, you can, but you're not actually echoing anything.

Comment: please, check you code here `... value="<?php $_SESSION['userNaam'] ...` you need to add `echo` after `<?php` to do it.

Comment: Aah I did, but then an error came into the field ghehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `echo` in your PHP string to see the value, for example:

```
<input class="field" id="userNaam" placeholder="Voornaam" type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userNaam'];?>" maxlength="20" minlength="1" size="17">
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I just changed the input in yours, but the only thing that changed was that the error in the field has left. xD :S